# Delete part of string from position to end in visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to remove a part of a string in an Excel cell. The string looks like this `23.08.2020 (21.08.2020)`. So basically everything from the opening bracket to the closing bracket (including the brackets). The date within the bracket differs. The date length also as single-digit days or months don't have a leading zero.

So I can detect the position of the first bracket with `InStr(1, columnA.Text, "(")`, but don't know how to proceed from here.

The outcome should look like this `23.08.2020`

Thanks

Comment: Wait so you just want to remove the the brackets and what is within? Do you need a VBA solution as you can easily do it with normal formula. What's `columnA.Text`?

Comment: Yes. Not every row has brackets. So I detect if there is a bracket. If that is the case I would like to delete everything from the opening bracket to the closing bracket.

Comment: If not every row has brackets, why don't you show us all possible strings to be processed? Do you imagine that we are mind readers and can supply a solution for everything, independent of the string itself? Does the string to be processed  have something else instead of "(21.08.2020)"?

Comment: Do you want to keep or throw away the space before the opening bracket?

Comment: If you want to just go with a non-VBA route, you can do: `=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("(",A1)-1),A1)` Just place it in the cell you want it and replace A1 for the cell you want it to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example that works:

```
Sub Macro()
'
' cells(1,1) = 23.08.2020 (21.08.2020)
' you change cells(1,1) with your need

'
   Dim dataResult As String

' Position of (, in this case 12
intPos = InStr(1, Cells(1, 1), "(")
If intPos > 0 Then
    ' ( found, so take up to :
    dataResult = Left(Cells(1, 1), intPos - 1)
    ' output of dataResult is 23.08.2020
Else
    ' ( not found, so take whole string
    dataResult = Cells(1, 1)
    
End If
Debug.Print dataResult ' in this case 21.08.2020 with the "white space" in last position

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function processString(str As String) As String
  processString = Split(str, " ")(0)
End Function
```

It can be tested like this:

```
Sub testProcessString()
   Dim strInit As String
  strInit = "23.08.2020 (21.08.2020)"
  'strInit = "23.08.2020"
  Debug.Print processString(strInit)
End Sub
```

Of course, instead of `strInit = "23.08.2020 (21.08.2020)"`, you can use `strInit = ActiveCell.value`

If you uncomment `'strInit = "23.08.2020"`, it will also return what you need...

Comment: Yes I tested your code with `strInit = "23.08.2020"`  but the `processString = arr` line never gets executed because split always returns an array. With no space in the string the array has only 1 element. Try your code with that line removed and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @CDP1802 Ups... Only now I understood your point. Thanks! I adapted the above function to  contain only a code line.